# Lookup Current Day and Time with QUERY or VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I currently pull in some appointment time slots based on the current time `now()` and extract the timeslots from the adjacent worksheet.

I now want to add in the current day of the week as an argument as well. Would I need to do something more advanced like `=query` or how could I extend this to the current `=vlookup`?

Here are what I got so far with QUERY and VLOOKUP:

```
=query(TimeSlots!C2:F25, select 2,3,4,5 where Col1 = Live!A2 & where Col2 = Live!B2)

=vlookup(timevalue(B2), {iferror(value(regexextract(TimeSlots!B2:B, "(.+)\s-"))),TimeSlots!C2:F}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, 1))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OOdLI-1j3d10LsfGdNPS4tOusx4AnRZvXzdgmrLvrSA/edit?usp=sharing

If you want to have a play and Make a Copy, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OOdLI-1j3d10LsfGdNPS4tOusx4AnRZvXzdgmrLvrSA/copy) links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this in good faith with your success at heart; things are a bit more difficult for you than they need be because you are breaking a couple of the unwritten rules of spreadsheet normalization. Most prominently, if you wish to use a cell in a formula elsewhere, the cell should be in a Sheets-native format. Try this:

1. Select TimeSlots column B
2. From the menus, choose Insert → Column Right
3. Rename B and C to, say… "Time Slot Begin" and "Time Slot End", respectively
4. Edit the data to recreate your ranges in this new split arrangement (included below if you want to copy-paste)
5. Armed with uniform, natively-calculable data sources, you can now use a formula to get the row(s) where the weekdays match *and* the current time is greater than the slot's start time *and* the current time is less than the slot's end time.

For example:

```
=FILTER( TimeSlots!A2:G29,
  A$2 = TimeSlots!A2:A29,
  MOD(B$2,1) > TimeSlots!B2:B29,
  MOD(B$2,1) < TimeSlots!C2:C29
)
```

Line by line, in English, it: narrows down the list of Time Slots to rows where
this sheet's day matches the TimeSlot's day, and
this sheet's time is after (greater than) the Time Slot's beginning, and
this sheet's time is before (less than) the Time Slot's ending.

Note that NOW() outputs a datetime, of which you are showing just the time *using "cosmetic" formatting*. To only look at the actual time component of the B2 date-time, I'm dividing by 1 day and keeping the remainder time.

Here are the aforementioned columns of time starts and ends, if you want to paste them into place. Column B:

```
Time Slot Begin
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
07:00:00
09:00:00
16:00:00
20:00:00
```

and Column C:

```
Time Slot End
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
08:59:00
15:59:00
19:59:00
06:59:00
```